# The connection to the server 192.168.1.2:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: connection, kubernetes

I am trying to install and run Kubernetes on my `Ubuntu 22.04LTS` machine. I followed the installation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) but I get the following errors when I try `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl get nodes` for example:

```
E1210 10:35:25.649853   16219 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1210 10:35:25.650138   16219 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1210 10:35:25.651789   16219 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1210 10:35:25.653224   16219 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1210 10:35:25.654932   16219 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 192.168.1.2:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I searched through the internet and tried many solutions but none of them worked for me!

result for `kubectl config view`:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
        server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
      name: kubernetes
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: kubernetes
        user: kubernetes-admin
      name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
    current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users:
    - name: kubernetes-admin
      user:
        client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
        client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
```

The `/etc/containerd/config.toml` file content:

```
#   Copyright 2018-2022 Docker Inc.

#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at

#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.

#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]
#root = "/var/lib/containerd"
#state = "/run/containerd"
#subreaper = true
#oom_score = 0

#[grpc]
#  address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0

#[debug]
#  address = "/run/containerd/debug.sock"
#  uid = 0
#  gid = 0
#  level = "info"

[plugins]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
      SystemdCgroup = true


  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  sandbox_image = "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.2"
```

Contents for `sudo nano $HOME/.kube/config`:

```
  GNU nano 6.2                  /home/a/.kube/config                            
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUMvakN>
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURJVENDQW>
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb2dJQkFBS0>
```

Comment: In my case continous restart of cluster with error:
The connection to the server 192.168.100.42:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? i am a beginner in k8 three node cluster node

Comment: i am a beginner as well. But I found out most of the time these kind of connection refused errors happen when the server you are trying to connect to is down. You should run the server then send a request. Also if you use the server often and don't want to start it everytime, you can add it as an OS service to systemctl. This way it will always startup automatically and you won't get a connection refused error again.